# Need help with LinqToXml grouping

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file that I'm trying to group by the attribute "Width".   Here is a snippet:

```
<nodes>
<FieldType Name="1000" OriginalName="1000" ScriptName="" SqlType="12" Width="1000" EnableValues="0" Scale="0" ForceMatch="0" ForceMatchCaseSensitive="0" SortAlphabetically="0" />
<FieldType Name="Varchar 1000" OriginalName="Varchar1000" ScriptName="" SqlType="12" Width="1000" EnableValues="0" Scale="0" ForceMatch="0" ForceMatchCaseSensitive="0" SortAlphabetically="0" />
<FieldType Name="Varchar 10001" OriginalName="Varchar1000" ScriptName="" SqlType="12" Width="1000" EnableValues="0" Scale="0" ForceMatch="0" ForceMatchCaseSensitive="0" SortAlphabetically="0" />
<FieldType Name="2000" OriginalName="1000" ScriptName="" SqlType="12" Width="200" EnableValues="0" Scale="0" ForceMatch="0" ForceMatchCaseSensitive="0" SortAlphabetically="0" />
<FieldType Name="Varchar 200" OriginalName="Varchar1000" ScriptName="" SqlType="12" Width="200" EnableValues="0" Scale="0" ForceMatch="0" ForceMatchCaseSensitive="0" SortAlphabetically="0" />
<FieldType Name="Varchar 2001" OriginalName="Varchar1000" ScriptName="" SqlType="12" Width="200" EnableValues="0" Scale="0" ForceMatch="0" ForceMatchCaseSensitive="0" SortAlphabetically="0" />
<FieldType Name="Y/N" ScriptName="" SqlType="12" Width="1" EnableValues="1" ForceMatch="1" Scale="0" ForceMatchCaseSensitive="0" SortAlphabetically="0" />
```

I want my parse to return 2 values, 1000 and 2000 since I want the unique widths.  The code I wrote is:

```
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\sample.xml");
        var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("FieldType")
                group xmlDoc by c.Attribute("Width") into cust_widths
                select new
                {
                    key = cust_widths.Key,
                    value = from val in cust_widths.Elements("Width") select (string)val
                };

        foreach (var name in q)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

But that still returns:  1000, 1000, 1000, 200, 200, 200.

Any idea what's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\sample.xml");
var q = 
    from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("FieldType")
    group c by c.Attribute("Width").Value into cust_widths
    select cust_widths.Key;

foreach (var name in q)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Your code had a few issues:

1. You were grouping the entire xmlDoc into the groupings instead of just the `FieldType` elements.
2. You were grouping by `XAttribute` objects instead of by the attributes' values.

There's actually an even simpler version of the query:

```
var q = xmlDoc
    .Descendants("FieldType")
    .Select(c => c.Attribute("Width").Value)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Man, I was close!  I guess the added value made each row unique.  Thanks, I like your simpler version even better, gotta love linq.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're grouping by the `XAttribute` object returned by the `Attribute()` operator, you're getting unique group keys for each single element. You need to use the `Value` property of the returned attribute to group by the attribute value.